# DisplayTag format number in Excel export

Tags: java, export-to-excel, displaytag

I have a little problem with DisplayTag and its Excel export. I have a table with columns containing strings starting with 0, like phone numbers or pin codes for example...

When I try to export them to an Excel file, Excel treats them as a number and deletes leading zero... (0012 becomes 12)

My config is the following

```
export.excel.class = org.displaytag.export.ExcelView
```

I already added a decorator (see below) that adds ="MYSTRING" when I export via Excel, but I don't like that much this solution, because you can see the trick on the Excel file...

```
public class QuotedExportDecorator implements DisplaytagColumnDecorator {

    @Override
    public Object decorate(Object value, PageContext pageContext, MediaTypeEnum media) {
        if (media.equals(MediaTypeEnum.EXCEL)) {
            value = "=\"" + value + "\"";
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```

Any other idea to go around this problem?

Comment: you might be passing arraylist to your display tag, in that can you please change the datatype of your all numbers to string, its just hack to try..

Comment: It's a string for sure because Integer cannot be displayed as 0002 without any process... (Same in database...)